# How can I get a "Any?" variable's real type in Swift

Tags: swift

I get property list from Mirror.children, it returns (label: String?, value: Any).
How can i get every value's real type.

```
var a: Int = 1
var b: Int? = nil
var c: Any?

c = a
getType(c) -> "Int"

c = b
getType(c) -> "Optional<Int>"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at `c.dynamicType`.

Comment: deprecated so cannot use this nowadays.

Answer (score 1):

[**Metatype Type**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html)

> A metatype type refers to the type of any type, including class types,
>   structure types, enumeration types, and protocol types.
>
> The metatype of a class, structure, or enumeration type is the name of
>   that type followed by .Type. The metatype of a protocol type—not the
>   concrete type that conforms to the protocol at runtime—is the name of
>   that protocol followed by .Protocol. For example, the metatype of the
>   class type SomeClass is SomeClass.Type and the metatype of the
>   protocol SomeProtocol is SomeProtocol.Protocol.
>
> You can use the postfix self expression to access a type as a value.
>   For example, SomeClass.self returns SomeClass itself, not an instance
>   of SomeClass. And SomeProtocol.self returns SomeProtocol itself, not
>   an instance of a type that conforms to SomeProtocol at runtime. You
>   can use a dynamicType expression with an instance of a type to access
>   that instance’s dynamic, runtime type as a value, as the following
>   example shows:

```
class SomeBaseClass {
    class func printClassName() {
        print("SomeBaseClass")
    }
}
class SomeSubClass: SomeBaseClass {
    override class func printClassName() {
        print("SomeSubClass")
    }
}
let someInstance: SomeBaseClass = SomeSubClass()
// The compile-time type of someInstance is SomeBaseClass,
// and the runtime type of someInstance is SomeBaseClass
someInstance.dynamicType.printClassName()
// prints "SomeSubClass
```

> Use the identity operators (=== and !==) to test whether an instance’s
>   runtime type is the same as its compile-time type.

```
if someInstance.dynamicType === someInstance.self {
    print("The dynamic type of someInstance is SomeBaseCass")
} else {
    print("The dynamic type of someInstance isn't SomeBaseClass")
}
// prints "The dynamic type of someInstance isn't SomeBaseClass"
```

> Use an initializer expression to construct an instance of a type from
>   that type’s metatype value. For class instances, the initializer
>   that’s called must be marked with the required keyword or the entire
>   class marked with the final keyword.

```
class AnotherSubClass: SomeBaseClass {
    let string: String
    required init(string: String) {
        self.string = string
    }
    override class func printClassName() {
        print("AnotherSubClass")
    }
}
let metatype: AnotherSubClass.Type = AnotherSubClass.self
let anotherInstance = metatype.init(string: "some string")
```